# Child div 100% height stretch parent div as well

Tags: css, html

I have a very simple scenario

Parent Div(height not specified)

Child div has some content and height set to 100%.

Now this child div force its parent to stretch to the full browser window.

Kindly guide.

Comment: If you want the parent div to be 100%, why not specify it as 100%?

Comment: That is default behaviour. You don't even need to set the height to 100%. Or perhaps I am misunderstanding the question. Kindly elaborate...

Comment: Include your html/css in the question.

Comment: I believe the question is how to prevent this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Set positions on both.

```
#ParentDiv {
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
}

#ChildDiv {
    position:absolute;
    /* top/left/right force it to dimensions of parent, if needed */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

The parent will stretch to fit the child.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ParentDiv {
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
}
#ChildDiv {
    position:absolute;
    /* top/left/right force it to dimensions of parent, if needed */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

Your ParentDiv height is AUTO , therefore the child force the Parent DIV to Expand to 100% of the Browser Height. Remove auto from the Parenet DIV. Your Problem will be solved.

Comment: auto is the default value for height when not specified. So removing height:auto would have no effect here. The code you quoted was from an answer, not from the question.